# Find confidence interval of a regression line at its center per group

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, prediction, confidence-interval

I have the following simulated data to fit a regression model, where `y`, `x1` are continuous variables and `x2` is a categorical variable.

```
y <- rnorm(100, 2, 3)
x1 <- rnorm(100, 2.5, 2.8)
x2 <- factor(c(rep(1,45), rep(0,55)))
```

I need to find the 95% confidence intervals for `y` when `x2 = 0` and `x1` equals to the mean within `x2 = 0`.

I did

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2)

tapply(x1, x2, mean)
#       0        1 
#3.107850 2.294103 

pred.dat <- data.frame(x1 = 3.107850, x2 = "0")

predict(mod, pred.dat, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)
#       fit      lwr      upr
#1 2.413393 1.626784 3.200003

predict(mod, pred.dat, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)
#       fit       lwr      upr
#1 2.413393 -3.473052 8.299839
```

I want to know whether I did this correctly or not. Also I want to know whether there is any easier way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setup**

```
set.seed(0)
y <- rnorm(100, 2, 3)
x1 <- rnorm(100, 2.5, 2.8)
x2 <- factor(c(rep(1,45), rep(0,55)))

mod <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2)
```

> 95% confidence intervals for `y` when `x2 = 0` and `x1` equals to the mean within `x2 = 0`.

---

> I want to know whether I did this correctly or not.

Your use of `predict` is correct.

> I want to know whether there is any easier way than this.

The `tapply` can be skipped if you do

```
pred.data <- data.frame(x1 = mean(x1[x2 == "0"]), x2 = "0")
#        x1 x2
#1 2.649924  0
```

Or you can do

```
pred.data <- setNames(stack(tapply(x1, x2, mean)), c("x1", "x2"))
#        x1 x2
#1 2.649924  0
#2 2.033328  1
```

so that you can get the result for both factor levels in one go.